# How to cookie a closed div on click in JS?

Tags: javascript, cookies, onclick

I got this html with some jQuery to close the div on click. I want to find a way in JS to make a cookie about this action. So the closed div won't appear again on a same session. Thanks.

```
<div class="bandeau">
  <a id="close" onClick="cookie">J'ai compris !</a>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#close").click(function(){
$(this).parent().hide(); return false;
</script>

});
});
```

Comment: That's a nice idea, what is your specific programming question?

Comment: Is there a simple way to do it in JS ?

Comment: Yes, there is, but that's not a specific programming question either. Please try something, and if you get stuck, then ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

i have done this before and i use library from https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

here the example:

```
$("#close").click(function(){
 // Set a cookie
    Cookies.set('hideDiv', 'hide');
});
```

and then make if condition if cookie is set

```
if($.cookie('hideDiv') == "hide"){
   $("#close").hide();
}else{
   $("#close").show();
}
```

hope this help, but in your case, you want the closed div won't appear on same session, so session storage more suit for your case.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Answer (score 0):

check w3school cookies:
[cookies](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

html(Include your jQuery too):

```
<div class="bandeau">
  <a id="close" >J'ai compris !</a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
//get cookies
function getCookie(name) {
    var dc = document.cookie;
    var prefix = name + "=";
    var begin = dc.indexOf("; " + prefix);
    if (begin == -1) {
        begin = dc.indexOf(prefix);
        if (begin != 0) return null;
    }
    else
    {
        begin += 2;
        var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", begin);
        if (end == -1) {
        end = dc.length;
        }
    }
    return decodeURI(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
} 
$(document).ready(function(){
      var myCookie = getCookie("isDivClosed");
        if (myCookie == null) {
          $(".bandeau").show();
        }
        else {
           $(".bandeau").hide();
        }
    $("#close").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().hide();
    // setting cookie
       document.cookie = 'isDivClosed=true; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 2045 00:00:01 GMT;';
         return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: Hello, thanks. It don't works for me. If I reload the page, div is still here.

Comment: tested on server/localhost. it wont work if you open html file by double click.

Comment: How to make it last to a session and not until cookies get cleared please ?